# Linux server periodically can't connect to itself (but all other connections work)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ssh, nagios

I upgraded our server from Ubuntu 15.04 to Ubuntu 15.10 today. The upgrade went smoothly, and everything worked as expected after the reboot.

However, about 20 minutes after booting the server is suddenly unable to connect to any port (http, ssh, etc.) on its own IP address--and just its own. Other computers on the LAN can still connect to the server without problems, and the server can connect to other computers on the network.

Then after another 20 minutes the local IP address seems to "wake up" so the server can connect to its own services again for a while before the problem repeats.

Specifically: all computers on the 192.168.0.0/24 network, including the server itself, can connect to services on the server's IP address 192.168.0.2. And then after a while suddenly the server itself cannot; it can't even ping its own IP address while happily serving everyone else. The server can also still connect to external servers (like using 8.8.8.8 for DNS), and it can connect to other computers on the LAN. It appears to be an IPv4 problem only.

I've disabled the firewall, changed the network card to another brand, and I've booted with the kernel from 15.04 but the problem persists. Restarting the NetworkManager doesn't help either.

I suspect some limiting might be enforced after the upgrade that prevents 192.168.0.2 from making too many connections to 192.168.0.2 (while still allowing other hosts to connect). But, even if this is the cause, I've no idea how to adjust it.

What's going on here, and how do I fix the problem?

Comment: The server itself cannot be ping'd from the console? Is it possible there is an IP conflict in your LAN?

Comment: The server can be pinged from other computers on the LAN. It just can't ping itself. I've checked for IP conflicts, and there are none (and if there were, the other computers would have trouble seeing the server, too).

Comment: Can you check if you have a  working `lo` interface using `ifconfig` and can you connect using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Is DHCP being used on the network?

Comment: Yes, but this particular network card is statically configured. For a while I suspected DHCP, too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason seems to be one of the last places I'd have looked: the culprit appears to be nagios. I've narrowed it down this far by selectively enabling and disabling services.

Apparently nagios fails on the generic SSH check. I don't see why this causes nagios to kill the local network address but I can live without this particular check.

Comment: I can't think of how Nagios would be blocking. Are you using any HIDS, such as OSSEC? Are there any IPTABLES rules active?

Comment: I agree, it's very odd. I'm not using any other monitoring software.

There are iptables rules active, but all of them via ufw. And, the problem began only right after I had upgraded to the next Ubuntu release. No settings have been changed anywhere.